# vb code - cancel message box

Tags: vb.net

I have this code that pops up a message box asking the user to input a date in mm/dd/yyyy format. When clicking cancel, it states to enter a valid date. If a user cancels the box, the message box should stop/disappears. But I have no idea how to do that.

Here's the code:

```
Try
    Dim docDate As String
    Dim batchNumber as String
    Dim dDate As Date
    Dim match As System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match

    'Define the regular expression to check dates
    Dim dateRegex As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(regExpression)
    'Prompt for the document date
    docDate = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox(“Enter the document date (mm/dd/yyyy):”, “Document Date”)
    'Match the input against the regex
    match = dateRegex.Match(docDate)

    'While it doesn't match the regex or a valid date continue to prompt for it
    Do While (Not match.Success Or Not Microsoft.VisualBasic.IsDate(docDate))
        'Alert the user of the problem
        Microsoft.VisualBasic.MsgBox(“Please enter a valid date in the format of mm/dd/yyyy.”)
        'Prompt for the document Date
        docDate = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox(“Enter the document date (mm/dd/yyyy):”, “Document Date”)
        'Match the input against the regex
        match = dateRegex.Match(docDate)
    Loop

    'Store the input dates in Date datatypes
    dDate = CDate(docDate)
    'Set the value into the global variables
    GBL_DOCUMENTDATE = dDate
    GBL_BATCH = batchNumber

Catch ex As Exception
    If (mapInterface = 1) Then
        Messagebox.Show(ex.Message, “DateInputTemplate Script Error”)
    End If
    Return False
End Try
```

Comment: Use a DateTimePicker control and you wont have to validate anything.  Please read [Ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: ...something, something, regex, now you have two problems...

Comment: I'd suggest reading the fine documentation, which will explain to you what `InputBox` returns when the user chooses "Cancel".  Then, adjust the conditions on your loop accordingly.

Comment: I Think there is something like if docDate = vbCancel then exit Do

Answer (score 2):

```
If MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid date in the format of mm/dd/yyyy.", "Question", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel) = DialogResult.OK
    docDate = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox(“Enter the document date (mm/dd/yyyy):”, “Document Date”)
Else
    'Do nothing? Get rid of the else statement if you don't need it
End If
```

So this pops up a message box with buttons OK and Cancel, and if the user clicks OK, then it proceeds to the code in the If statement block.

Answer (score -1):

Here is how i would do it.

```
    Dim valid as boolean
    Do
        valid = true
        docDate = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox(“Enter the document date (mm/dd/yyyy):”, “Document Date”)
        match = dateRegex.Match(docDate)
        If (docDate = "")
            'they clicked cancel leave the loop
            docDate = Date.Now().toString("MM\/dd\/yyyy")
            Exit Do
        ElseIf (Not match.Success Or Not Microsoft.VisualBasic.IsDate(docDate)) Then
            valid = false
            Microsoft.VisualBasic.MsgBox(“Please enter a valid date in the format of mm/dd/yyyy.”)
        End If
    Loop until valid
```

So will ask to enter document date. If they press cancel instead of entering a date and pressing the docDate becomes empty string so the if statement checks this and sets docDate to todays date.
If they entered a date and the date entered is not a valid date then the msgbox will appear and the loop will start again and ask for the document date.